# Further spliting dataset

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, model-selection, dataset, hyperparameter

I need to to feature selection, parameter tuning and model evaluation. My question is if it is valid to split dataset:

1. to train-test set
2. Then further train set to train-validation1 set
3. Then further train set ( from 2.) to train-validation2 set

Then I will do feature selection on train-validation2 (train for training and validation2 for choosing the best features) set, merge both and do parameter tuning on train-validation1 (train for training and validation1 to for choosing best hyper parameters) set and then merge it to do train final model on train set and evaluate on test set.

Is this procedure valid or I should split dataset differently? I have found that you could split dataset to train, validation and test set. And in another resource I have found that is possibly to split dataset for training,feature selection, parameter tunning and test set.